Holes in clothes in render mode

I created clothes for my model in Marvelous Designer, but after I imported it into Blender, a lot of holes appeared in render mode. The topology seems to be fine, but on the render there are these holes and I have no idea what this could be and what it could have to do with.


Check that the normals are correct on the clothes by enabling Face Orientation on the viewport overlay dropdown. (Should be all blue). Also: Although we can't see any details it looks as if you have some objects in the Outliner disabled in Viewport mode but still enabled in Render mode so it's possible that they are masking the missing sections when rendering.

thank you for your promptness. I managed to solve the problem. I don't know why, but changing the type from fbx to obj solved it by itself

In my experience, this only has to do with the fact that either no correct UV mapping was created in Marvelous Designer (by editing the UVs in the "UV Editor"), or a possibly used UDIM texture was not correctly applied/set in Blender (Shader > switch from Single Image to UDIM Tiles). In both cases we would need more information from you.

OK, I have now tested it myself, this is most probably the second case, which is why I am closing the question for the time being as duplicate. Feel free to add more details to the question and reopen it if necessary.
